# Android: stopping a runnable and restarting it fresh

Tags: android, runnable

I just implemented a simple app that randomly changes the color of the screen and displays the hex code of the color in a textview. After lots of searching (expecially many posts on stackoverflow), I almost have code that does what I want; there is just one discrepancy. When I click to restart the color flashing runnable, it 'resumes' from where it left off, i.e. it will not do the full delay initially, but will seemingly only delay what time was probably left off when I stopped it.

My complete code is below. Currently, I have a short press to start the screen color flashing runnable, and a long press to stop it.

```
package com.example.colorflashingproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//initialize a boolean variable (true or false only) 
//to check whether the overlay is tinted or not
boolean isTinted = false;
boolean colorIsFlashing = false;

//initialize a handler that we will use to loop a section of code
//that constantly changes the color of the screen
public Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//this creates the UI and screen view, and sets up some
//other aspects of the program
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set the current view in the user interface as our xml file:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set the background color, and the initial overlay tint:
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.background_view)).setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    //create the overlayView variable that replesents our overlay for tinting
    View overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay_view);

    //implement a method that will listen for a short press
    overlayView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //implement function to change tint of our overlay
            if (!colorIsFlashing) {
                colorIsFlashing = true;
                mHandler.post(startColorFlashing);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });     

    //implement a method that will listen for long press:
    overlayView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            //stop the color flashing if it was started:
            if (colorIsFlashing) {
                colorIsFlashing = false;
                stopColorFlashing();
            }

            //return true tells the system that the long press registered
            //return false doesn't. A false return would cause
            //the long click to register as a short click as well
            return true;
        }
    });

}


//this function generates a random color and sets it to the screen
public void randomChangeTint(){
    //generate random color components:
    int randa = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randr = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randg = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randb = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randColor = Color.argb(randa, randr, randg, randb); 

    //convert color integer to string:
    String strColor = String.format("#%08X", randColor);

    //set overlay to our generated random color:
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)).setBackgroundColor(randColor);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(strColor);
}


//this is our 'runnable' that randomly sets the screen color over
//an interval of time in milliseconds (timeInterval)
public Runnable startColorFlashing = new Runnable(){
    //set overlay view to randomly switch colors
    int timeInterval=600;
    public void run() {
        if (colorIsFlashing){
            randomChangeTint();
        } else {

        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, timeInterval);
    }
};


//this method stops the color flashing:
public void stopColorFlashing() {

    //pauses the runnable:
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(startColorFlashing);

    //re-initializes the runnable as an empty one
    startColorFlashing = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            //empty, nothing here
        }
    };
}
}
```

If I leave out the

```
    //re-initializes the runnable as an empty one
    startColorFlashing = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            //empty, nothing here
        }
    };
```

part of stopColorFlashing(), then short pressing the screen multiple times in a row seems to start the runnable over and over again, and after stopping it then restarting it with a short press, it starts flashing again seemingly resuming from where it was stopped. I'd like it to start 'anew'.

I've tried some stuff with Thread.start() and Thread.pause(), but can't figure that out. Is there a way to 'kill' or 'destroy' a runnable?

I'm new to java (I know matlab), and any ideas or recommendations are appreciated. I'm sure my code is written extremely poorly and ineficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution by following the AOSP deskclock example of how it moves the time display every minute or so in screen saver mode. The key I think was the removeMessages method for the Handler (that is a Method, correct?). Also, rather than having a Runnable that constantly posted a UI update, I simply have the called UI update method generateRandomColor() to send a delayed message to the handler, which then calls the method generateRandomColor() again, thus causing a loop. I think this might still not be the best way, but it is concise and works.

The code below does exactly what I wanted it to do. I hope this helps someone searching for similar issues with handlers...

```
package com.example.testproject04;

/* import necessary libraries for 
 * our objects classes and widgets 
 * that we use here
 */
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Message;

/* declare the main class/activity of this program */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* initialize a boolean variable (true or false only) to 
 * check whether the screen is flashing new colors or not */
boolean colorIsFlashing = false;

/* update interval in milliseconds */
public int updateDelay = 800; 

/* 'message' to change color (used by handler) */
int CHANGE_COLOR_MSG = 0x0; 

/* this creates the UI and screen view, 
 * and sets up some other aspects of the program */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* set the current view in the 
     * user interface as our xml file:
     */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* set the background color, 
     * and the initial overlay tint:
     */
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.background_view)).setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    /* create the overlayView variable that 
     * represents our overlay for tinting
     */
    View overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay_view);

    /* implement a method that will listen for a short press, 
     * when short press occurs, if the screen is not currently 
     * flashing, it will start flashing periodically
     */
    overlayView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!colorIsFlashing){
                colorIsFlashing = true;
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CHANGE_COLOR_MSG, updateDelay);
            } 
        }
    }); 

    /* implement a listener for long presses on the screen, 
     * when a long press occurs, 
     * if the screen is flashing, it will stop 
     */
    overlayView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (colorIsFlashing) {
                colorIsFlashing = false;
                mHandler.removeMessages(CHANGE_COLOR_MSG);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }); 

}

/* initialize a handler that we will use 
 * to change the color of the screen 
 */
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        if (m.what == CHANGE_COLOR_MSG) {
            generateRandomColor();
        }
    }
};

/* this function generates a random color
 *  and sets it to the screen 
 */
public void generateRandomColor(){
    if (!colorIsFlashing) return;

    /* generate random color components: */
    int randa = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randr = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randg = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randb = (int) Math.round((int) 0xff * (float) Math.random());
    int randColor = Color.argb(randa, randr, randg, randb); 

    /* convert color integer to string: */
    String strColor = String.format("#%08X", randColor);

    /* set overlay to our generated random color
     *  and update textview to display color in hex code
     */
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)).setBackgroundColor(randColor);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(strColor);

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CHANGE_COLOR_MSG, updateDelay);
}

}
```

Extra search tags/info: looping code within the UI thread, stopping a loop in android activity using handlers, remove messages from handler, send delayed message to handler

Comment: This all looks so complicated to mee for just let a color change. Why not just a timer which fires at predetermined times?

Comment: I haven't learned how to make a timer yet... guess will have to look into it! Thanks for the pointer...